# StringBuilder.insert()

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I need to compare two strings.

The input value is like

> SELECT * FROM ds WHERE ds.age='24';

The text against which it needs to be compared being

> SELECT * FROM ds WHERE ds.status='VALID' AND ds.age='24';

Since "ds.status='VALID' AND" is a static string, I thought of inserting it into the input and then compare it with the original string.

So I created a StringBuilder object and

> query.insert(query.indexOf("WHERE"), "ds.status='VALID' AND");

but the output was

> SELECT * FROM ds ds.status='VALID' AND WHERE ds.age='24';

Also, indexOf() cannot be inputted with a static position since it can vary with the input.
Is there any way to find the index of the last letter of the word "WHERE"?

The work-around I found is

> String query = query.replace("WHERE", "WHERE ds.status='VALID' AND");

Is this the best possible method?

Comment: why not just add the number of letters --> indexOf("WHERE ")+6

Comment: I would use the replace but with spaces `query.replace(" WHERE ", " WHERE ds.status='VALID' AND ");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the replace is a lot cleaner and easier to read -  like Peter Lawrey's comment:

```
query.replace(" WHERE ", " WHERE ds.status='VALID' AND ");
```

No having to worry about fencepost errors or magic numbers and so much clearer in intent!

*EDIT*

That would be:

```
query.toString().replace(" WHERE ", " WHERE ds.status='VALID' AND ");
```

(Replace on StringBuilder takes indexes)

Comment: Ok, so I think I would better go with replace(). Thanks all. :) But I would definitely like to learn why insert() throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert%28int,%20boolean%29), the StringIndexOutofBoundsException is thrown when the offset is invalid -  I can't see how this would happen given when running `query.insert(query.indexOf("WHERE"), "ds.status='VALID' AND");` on `SELECT * FROM ds WHERE ds.age='24';`, is it possible you ran the code on a string that didn't contain "WHERE"?

Answer (score 2):

```
query.insert(query.indexOf("WHERE") + "WHERE".length(), " ds.status='VALID' AND");
```

Comment: Not entirely. Replace `query.indexOf("WHERE" + "WHERE".length())` with `query.indexOf("WHERE") + "WHERE".length()` or even better: `query.indexOf("WHERE") + 5`

Comment: add some spaces or it will result in ``SELECT * FROM ds WHEREds.status='VALID' ANDds.age='24';`` ;)

Comment: @Hachi set a blank before the String need to insert.

Comment: q.insert(query.indexOf("WHERE") + 5, " ds.status='VALID' AND"); gives java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 22 exception. From this I understand that as per java the string is not 22 characters long. But SELECT * FROM ds WHERE ds.age='24'; does contain 22 chars!

Comment: @Student what the `q` is?I think you should use `query`.

Comment: Oh yes plucury, you are right. Since I can't edit the comment,  `query.insert(query.indexOf("WHERE") + 5, " ds.status='VALID' AND");` gives `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 22 exception.` From this I understand that as per java the string is not 22 characters long. But SELECT * FROM ds WHERE ds.age='24'; does contain 22 chars!

Comment: @Student So you still got error?How about show me more codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("SELECT * FROM ds WHERE ds.age='24'");
    str.insert(str.lastIndexOf("WHERE") + 6, "ds.status='VALID' AND ");
```